# Xamarin MultiBinding Needs BindingContext from higher ancestor level or named Items in XAML tree

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, multibinding

I am Building a rectangular Grid of Homogeneous Buttons with Dynamic Rows and Columns to Be set at Runtime. The Code is in Xamarin. All the latest versions etc.
Entire Project can be Downloaded here: https://github.com/BicycleMark/XamSweeper
The Problem I am having is the MultiBinding Portion of the XAML. Any review or suggestions would be super-excellent

I used Nested StackPanels to create the Grid like this:

[image]

I succeeded at creating a MultiValueConverter for **sizing** the Buttons which are appearing correctly. I have Tested the Converter with a Unit Test and it functions as Expected. the [R,C] is printed in the Test of each Button. These are pulled from Model which is bound Correctly

The problem I am having is in Linking the MultiBinding to 3 Items I need to calculate Size for the Buttons:

The **Width** of Each Button is calculated with these three parameters

1. **ActualWidth** of Frame Holding the Buttons
2. Number of **Columns** Of Buttons Of Model
3. Spacing or Padding between each Button
4. If any [1..3] are null **return 50**  <--- This is What I return because my Binding is not working

The **Height** of Each Button is calculated with these three parameters

1. **ActualHeight** of Frame Holding the Buttons
2. Number of **Rows** Of Buttons Of Model
3. Spacing or Padding between each Button
4. If any [1..3] are null **return 50** <--- This is What I return because my Binding is not working

Here is the Converter Described:

```
    public class SizeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length <3 || values[2] == null || values[1] == null || values[0] == null)
            return 50;
        int numItems = (int)values[2];
        int separatorSize = (int)values[1]; 
        double frameSize = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]) ;
        
        int totalSeparatorSize = (numItems - 1) * separatorSize;
        int remainingArea = System.Convert.ToInt32(frameSize) - totalSeparatorSize;
        return remainingArea / numItems;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And Its Unit Test Which Passes:

```
 [DataRow(100, 2, 4)]
    [DataTestMethod]
    public void Test_Piece_Sizing(double frameSize, int separatorSize, int numItems)
    {
        var sizeConverter = new SizeConverter();
        object[] values = new object[] { frameSize, separatorSize, numItems };
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0,sizeConverter.Convert(values, typeof(int), null, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    }
```

The issue at hand is when I bind My Values in Xamarin My Converter gets Null passed from my XAML
Here is the XAML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sweeper.Controls;assembly=Sweeper"
    xmlns:cvt="clr-namespace:Sweeper.Views.Converters;assembly=Sweeper"
    x:Class="Sweeper.Views.GamePage"    
    Title="Game"
    x:Name="page">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <cvt:SizeConverter  x:Key="SizeConverter" />
        <cvt:CoordinateConverter x:Key="CoordinateConverter" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="DarkSeaGreen" CornerRadius="15" Padding="15">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*,3*">
            <Frame Grid.Row="0" Padding="0">
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*" Padding="0" >
                    <Frame Grid.Column="0">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CoordinateConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Board.Rows" />
                                    <Binding Path="Board.Columns" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Label.Text>
                        </Label>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame Grid.Column="1">
                        <Button Text="Ok"></Button>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame Grid.Column="2">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Game.Time}"/>
                    </Frame>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
            <Frame Grid.Row="1" x:Name="frameButtons" Padding="4" HasShadow="True" >
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="4" 
                             BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Board.RowItems}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding}" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Frame Padding="0"  HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" >
                                            <Button  Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Body" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Navy"/>
                                            <Frame.WidthRequest>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SizeConverter}" >
                                                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                        <Binding Source="x:Reference frameButtons" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                                        <Binding Source="x:Reference frameButtons" Path="Padding" />
                                                        <Binding Source="x:Reference frameButtons" Path="BindingContext.Board.Columns" />
                                                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </Frame.WidthRequest>
                                            <Frame.HeightRequest>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SizeConverter}" >
                                                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                        <Binding Source="x:Reference frameButtons" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                                        <Binding Source="x:Reference frameButtons" Path="Padding" />
                                                        <Binding Source="x:Reference frameButtons" Path="BindingContext.Board.Rows" />
                                                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </Frame.HeightRequest>
                                        </Frame >
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentPage>
```

The Converter is Getting Called but I am passing 3 nulls each time. This is the Binding Error I am trying to repair

Entire Project can be Downloaded here: https://github.com/BicycleMark/XamSweeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Converter is Getting Called but I am passing 3 nulls each time.

You could try to set the `BindingContext` to the `Frame` like:

```
<Frame Padding="0"  HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" BindingContext="{x:Reference frameButtons}">
   <Button  Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Body" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Navy" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
   <Frame.WidthRequest>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SizeConverter}" >

         <MultiBinding.Bindings>
           <Binding Path="ActualWidth" />
           <Binding Path="Padding" />
           <Binding Path="BindingContext.Board.Columns" />
         </MultiBinding.Bindings>
      </MultiBinding>
   </Frame.WidthRequest>
   <Frame.HeightRequest>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SizeConverter}" >
         <MultiBinding.Bindings>
           <Binding Path="ActualHeight" />
           <Binding Path="Padding" />
           <Binding Path="BindingContext.Board.Rows" />
         </MultiBinding.Bindings>
      </MultiBinding>
    </Frame.HeightRequest>
 </Frame >
```

then you could get the value in your `Converter`.

But `ActualWidth` seems not be an existing bindable property.

Comment: yes that is beginning to send values into my converter. I will have to figure out an alternative for AcutalWidth/ActualHeight. I will Mark it as answer after I find the rest of the answer.  on Actual... Hmm Maybe a Markup???

Comment: @MarkWardell Do you want to average the frames ? If yes,maybe it's the width of the device screen.

Comment: Okay I slept and am back at it an quite refreshed. This lack of availability of ActualWidth/Height put s a true fly in my ointment... Another point of note is that I was attaching to a Padding and I should have been Attaching to one of the fields of the Padding. In WPF we can bind to ActualWidth/AcutaulHeight.

Comment: I may want to Consider Overriding Layout or Layout<T>

Comment: On Average Question... I want each child Frame to be of Uniform Size. In WPF we do this from a UniformGrid.

Comment: @MarkWardell This may be the difference between platforms.You need to think of some other way to instead of  `ActualWidth/Height`.Anyway, I think that's a new question.